# Is it possible to enable X-Ray tracing on an EventBridge Eventbus via CDK?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-xray, aws-event-bridge

The ability for EventBridge to trace events via X-ray was added earlier this year, see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-x-ray-tracing-with-amazon-eventbridge/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-related-service-xray.html.

However, this functionality does not yet seem available via the AWS CDK and it seems it might not even be available via the EventBus Cloudformation template. This is the code from CDK that creates the bus

```
const eventBus = new CfnEventBus(this, 'Resource', {
  name: eventBusName,
  eventSourceName,
});
```

which I assume is directly mapping to the CFN template (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-eventbus.html)

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::Events::EventBus",
  "Properties" : {
      "EventSourceName" : String,
      "Name" : String
    }
}
```

Does anyone know different? If not where would we start to implement this?